# ObjectId is not serialized to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, scalatra, objectid, json4s

I am using scalatra and configured my servlet to always return JSON (as described in the respective guide). Using the MongoDB and Salat leads me to the point where I read a MongoDBObject back into my case class - which seems to work great.

My case class:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.novus.salat.annotations.raw.Key

case class Player(_id: ObjectId, firstName: String, ...)
```

Printing the case class object outputs this:

```
Player(547489ee93f4272e548ded63,Peter,...)
```

As you can see, the objectid is a org.bson.types.ObjectId.
The automatical serialization to JSON sends this to the browser:

```
{"_id":{},"firstName":"Peter",...}
```

Where is my ObjectID? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following on the web:
https://gist.github.com/dozed/5631680

After a small test it seems as if all I had to do was changing the code in my servlet from

```
protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
```

to

```
protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats + new ObjectIdSerializer
```

and add

```
import org.json4s.mongo.ObjectIdSerializer
```

Maybe this will help another Scalatra-NOOB... ;-)